# Replace a block with special characters to another block using sed in ubuntu

Tags: regex, bash, sed, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to replace some lines in a config file of tripwire automatically:

I have the following section in the file:

```
#
# Critical devices
#
(
  rulename = "Devices & Kernel information",
  severity = $(SIG_HI),
)
{
    /dev        -> $(Device) ;
    /proc       -> $(Device) ;
}
```

and I want to replace it with this (the change starts from the line of /dev/pts)

```
#
# Critical devices
#
(
  rulename = "Devices & Kernel information",
  severity = $(SIG_HI),
)
{
    /dev        -> $(Device) ;
    /dev/pts        -> $(Device) ;
        #/proc                  -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/devices           -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/net               -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/tty               -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/sys               -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/cpuinfo           -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/modules           -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/mounts            -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/dma               -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/filesystems       -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/interrupts        -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/ioports           -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/scsi              -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/kcore             -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/self              -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/kmsg              -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/stat              -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/loadavg           -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/uptime            -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/locks             -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/meminfo           -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/misc              -> $(Device) ;
}
```

I am trying to figure a command with sed but I am not succeeding.

I would appreciate if someone can advice me what to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sed with an alternate regex demiter like `~` since `/` is present in your search and replace patterns.

Create a file call `new.txt` with this data:

```
    /dev/pts        -> $(Device) ;
    #/proc                  -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/devices           -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/net               -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/tty               -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/sys               -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/cpuinfo           -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/modules           -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/mounts            -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/dma               -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/filesystems       -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/interrupts        -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/ioports           -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/scsi              -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/kcore             -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/self              -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/kmsg              -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/stat              -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/loadavg           -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/uptime            -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/locks             -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/meminfo           -> $(Device) ;
    /proc/misc              -> $(Device) ;
```

Then run this command:

```
sed -e '/\/proc/{s/.*//; r new.txt' -e '}' file
```

**Output:**

```
#
# Critical devices
#
(
  rulename = "Devices & Kernel information",
  severity = $(SIG_HI),
)
{
    /dev        -> $(Device) ;

    /dev/pts        -> $(Device) ;
        #/proc                  -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/devices           -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/net               -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/tty               -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/sys               -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/cpuinfo           -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/modules           -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/mounts            -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/dma               -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/filesystems       -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/interrupts        -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/ioports           -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/scsi              -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/kcore             -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/self              -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/kmsg              -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/stat              -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/loadavg           -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/uptime            -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/locks             -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/meminfo           -> $(Device) ;
        /proc/misc              -> $(Device) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't do anything. only returns the whole file text and does not replace the text. I want explicitly to replace the whole two lines with other two lines. I mean to have the possibility to quote explicitly the whole line text inside sed and also in the replacement string to write the whole line text that should be there. How to do that ? Thanks

Comment: @user1902346 Sed is a line reader, you cannot search regex for more than one line unless you grab the next line first.

Comment: Thanks. So maybe sed is not the right command for me. Any other command that can fit for me more than sed ?

Comment: Why even search for whole line when `-> $(Device) ;` part is same in original and replaced text?

Comment: @user1902346 Sed is as good as anything else for this, maybe add a little more detail to the question as it isn't entirely clear what you want, do you want to match only when the two lines occur together ?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks